# Creating a cmd task with all the private ip address details collected from gather_facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running an Ansible playbook from my local laptop to AWS connecting on the public IP address. The infra is being spun up by terraform so I don't know the private IP address before hand.  I have around 8 hosts. I want to create a command which needs to have all the private IPs of all 8 hosts.

I have tried `gather_facts` method but I don’t know how to get values from all 8 hosts assigned to some variable, so that I can use it at another task.

```
    - name: initialise cluster
      command:
        cmd: /opt/splunk/bin/splunk splunk init shcluster-config -auth admin:changed -mgmt_uri https://{{ private ip address of host1 }}:8089 -replication_port 34567 -replication_factor 2 -conf_deploy_fetch_url https://{private ip address of host2}:8089 -secret mykey -shcluster_label shcluster1
      become: true
      become_user: root
      ignore_errors: yes
      async: 10
      poll: 0

- name: set cluster 
      command:
        cmd: /opt/splunk/bin/splunk splunk bootstrap shcluster-captain -servers_list "{{private ip of 1st host}}:8089,{{ private ip of 2nd host }}:8089,{{ private ip of 3rd host }}:8089,etc..." -auth <username>:<password>
      become: true
      become_user: root
      ignore_errors: yes
      async: 10
      poll: 0
```

How do I run a `set_facts` command which will get the private ip from each hosts and assign it to a cmd task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Run a set_facts command which will get private ip from each host."***

A: You can either run a command, for example,

```yaml
  - shell: 'ifconfig em0 | grep inet | cut -w -f3'
    register: out
```

and use the registered variable

```yaml
  cmnd_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['out', 'stdout']))) }}"
```

, or you can run the module *setup* and use the facts, for example

```yaml
  fact_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_em0', 'ipv4']))) }}"
```

Notes:

- Fit the command to your needs.
- When you use *setup* the format of facts may vary among the operating systems.
- There might be more addresses assigned to an interface. In this case, you'll have to decide which one to use.
- Create the list of the servers. For example,

```yaml
  servers_list: "{{ cmnd_ip.values()|
                    product(['8089'])|
                    map('join', ':')|
                    join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  servers_list: 10.1.0.51:8089,10.1.0.52:8089,10.1.0.53:8089
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    fact_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                          map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_em0', 'ipv4']))) }}"

    cmnd_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                      zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                          map('extract', hostvars, ['out', 'stdout']))) }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Get facts
      block:

        - setup:
        - debug:
            var: fact_ip
          run_once: true

      tags: fact

    - name: Run command
      block:

        - shell: 'ifconfig em0 | grep inet | cut -w -f3'
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: cmnd_ip
          run_once: true

      tags: cmnd
```

given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

gives (abrdiged)

```yaml
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]
ok: [test_03]
ok: [test_02]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  fact_ip:
    test_01:
    - address: 10.1.0.51
      broadcast: 10.1.0.51
      netmask: 255.255.255.255
      network: 10.1.0.51
    test_02:
    - address: 10.1.0.52
      broadcast: 10.1.0.52
      netmask: 255.255.255.255
      network: 10.1.0.52
    test_03:
    - address: 10.1.0.53
      broadcast: 10.1.0.53
      netmask: 255.255.255.255
      network: 10.1.0.53

TASK [shell] *********************************************************************************
changed: [test_01]
changed: [test_02]
changed: [test_03]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  cmnd_ip:
    test_01: 10.1.0.51
    test_02: 10.1.0.52
    test_03: 10.1.0.53
```